# XSD: Importing complex types doesn't work

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a XML schema `schema.xsd` with custom types in outside file `types.xsd`. I don't know why my complex type `typeComplex` is doesn't validated correctly. Simple types like `typeSimple` works ok. What wrong with that ?

Eclipse say:

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'a'. One of '{"http://www.example.org/types":a}' is expected.

schema.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/schema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:t="http://www.example.org/types">

    <xs:import schemaLocation="types.xsd" namespace="http://www.example.org/types" />

    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="simple" type="t:typeSimple" />
                <xs:element name="complex" type="t:typeComplex" />
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

types.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/types" xmlns="http://www.example.org/types"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:simpleType name="typeSimple">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:length value="3" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:complexType name="typeComplex">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="b" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

text.xml - not valid with xsd - Why ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://www.example.org/schema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/schema schema.xsd " xmlns:t="http://www.example.org/types">
    <simple>XXX</simple>
    <complex>
        <a></a> <!-- not valid here; Eclipse say: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'a'. One of '{"http://www.example.org/types":a}' is expected. -->
        <b></b>
    </complex>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your instance document is declared as being an instance of the "root" type inside the namespace "http://www.example.org/schema". This is fine. Within this document you want to use types from the namespace "http://www.example.org/types" and so you have included this namespace with a prefix. This is also fine.

However when you go to use the types contained in the "http://www.example.org/types" namespace you are ignoring the prefix you defined in your xmlns declaration.

The correct way to reference these types:

```
<root xmlns="http://www.example.org/schema" 
      xmlns:t="http://www.example.org/types">
  <simple>XXX</simple>
  <complex>
    <t:a></t:a>
    <t:b></t:b>
  </complex>
</root>
```

**UPDATE**

Your alternatives are:

Use unqualified types - just change your schema definitions to make `elementFormDefault="unqualified"`. This means you can now do this:

```
<root xmlns="http://www.example.org/schema">
  <simple xmlns="">XXX</simple>
  <complex xmlns="">
    <a></a>
    <b></b>
  </complex>
</root>
```

Or, don't use XSD schema. This means you can just use well-formed xml:

```
<root>
  <simple>XXX</simple>
  <complex>
    <a></a>
    <b></b>
  </complex>
</root>
```

Comment: Can it be done without the use of `t:` namespace ? I need that validated xml will be in one namespace.

Answer (score 1):

I did was i want using `<xs:include />`.

schema.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/schema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:include schemaLocation="types.xsd" />

    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="simple" type="typeSimple" />
                <xs:element name="complex" type="typeComplex" />
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

types.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:simpleType name="typeSimple">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:length value="3" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:complexType name="typeComplex">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="b" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thank's a buch! The ` <xs:include schemaLocation="types.xsd" />` instead of `<xs:import ... />` solved my problem too.